# Why the output is different, java inheritance?

Tags: java

I've got 2 classes, car extends vehicle, Why, when I'm trying to print a new created car object the output isn't equal as I thought.

I'm running it on Eclipse, java 11

```
public class vehicle_13 {
    private int years;
    public vehicle_13(int y) {
        years=y;
    }
    public int years() {
        return years;
    }
    public String driving() {
        return "Can drive";
    }
    public int speed() {
        return 50;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "years = "+years()+"\n"+this.driving()+"\n"+"speed = "+this.speed()
        +"\n"+this.money_per(); // driving() = this.driving()
        }
    public int money_per() {
        return years*10;
    }

}
```

```
public class car_13 extends vehicle_13 {
    public car_13(int y) {
        super(0);
    }
    public int speed() {
        System.out.println(super.driving());
        return super.speed()*2;
    }

}
```

I expect the output of this car object .toString() to be:

```
years = 0
Can drive
Can drive
speed = 100
0
```

but the actual output is:

```
Can drive
years = 0
Can drive
speed = 100
0
```

Comment: All of the arguments are evaluated before `toString()` returns.

Comment: Add your `main()` method to your question. Use [Edit].

Comment: @PM77-1 main is basically 2 lines long: car_13 aa=new car_13(0); System.out.println(car);

Comment: @chrylis ah, okay thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you concatenate the string like this:

```
return "years = " + years() + "\n" + this.driving() + "\n" 
     + "speed = " + this.speed() + "\n" + this.money_per();
```

It has to execute each of the methods *before* it creates the string. After all, it's the result of executing the method that gets added to the string. So the `println` in the `speed` method is called when `this.speed()` is evaluated, *then* the concatenated string is returned by `toString`,  and *then* the result is passed to `System.out.println`. So the `println` in `speed` runs before the `println` in `main`, not in the middle of it.

P.S: Long concatenation like this, is better suited to the `String.format` method

```
return String.format("years = %d\n%d\nspeed = %d\n%d",
            years(), driving(), speed(), money_per());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called super.driving in the sub-class and that is what is evaluated first. Therefore it prints out "Can drive" first, before the result of the toString as you expected.